# How to implement spring annotations from an api swagger in a class controller?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am develop a RESTfull web service which uses swagger with `swagger-codegen-maven-plugin`to create the models, controles and the api class (which is an interface with spring annotatios).

The plugin in the pom.xml is the next:

```
     <plugin>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <inputSpec>C:\API.yaml</inputSpec>
                        <language>spring</language>
                        <configOptions>
                            <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                            <useTags>true</useTags>
                            <sourceFolder>/</sourceFolder>
                        </configOptions>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>           
    </plugin>
```

When I want to create a new controller class (it is different from the one created by Swagger) this implements the api class and the signing of the methods, however, this class does not write annotations in the parameters of the methods (Example: @RequestParam, @RequestHeader, etc.)

Api Interface;

```
public interface Api{

    @RequestMapping(value = "/class-services",
        method = RequestMethod.GET)
    default ResponseEntity<XXXType> getClass(@ApiParam(value = "id" ,required=true) @RequestHeader(value="Id", required=true) String id) {
        // do some magic!
        return new ResponseEntity<XXXType>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

Controller class:

```
@Controller
public class controller implements Api {

    public ResponseEntity<XXXType> getClass(String id) {
        // do some magic!
       return new ResponseEntity<XXXType>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

This result in swagger-ui defines every parameters like 'query'. Swagger does not distinguish the header parameter type.

I want to know if exist some way to extend the annotatios next to interface when I implement the Api class, (I want to know copy and paste the sign methods).

Note: I am using Java 8 for the LocalTime and LocalDate class.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The `<delegatePattern>true</delegatePattern>` parameter inside the `<configOptions>` of swagger-codegen-maven-plugin helped me to resolve the similar problem.